# Make a met condition delayed with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an animation with collision detection, that when the condition is met, it waits about 500 ms to trigger the next condition. I've tried the .delay() method, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using jQuery and jQuery API for other parts.

```
if (r1x>=p1x && r1x<=p1y){
    planta1.style.width="50px";
    planta1.style.top="-90px"
    planta1.style.left="30px"
    planta1.src="imagens/jogo_1/planta1_2.png";
    planta1nmr=1;

    if (planta1nmr==1){
      planta1.style.width="100px";
      planta1.style.top="-100px"
      planta1.style.left="10px"
      planta1.src="imagens/jogo_1/planta1_3.png";
      planta1nmr=2;

      if(planta1nmr==2){
        planta1.style.width="100px";
        planta1.style.top="-110px"
        planta1.style.left="10px"
        planta1.src="imagens/jogo_1/planta1_4.png";
        planta1nmr=3;

        if (planta1nmr==3){
          planta1.style.width="100px";
          planta1.style.top="-120px"
          planta1.style.left="10px"
          planta1.src="imagens/jogo_1/planta1_5.png";
          coracao1.style.visibility="visible";
          coracao1.style.top="500px";
          coracao1.style.left="95px";
          pontosjogo1facil++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What the hell are you doing? You set it as 1 and immediately check if it's 1 in the same scope?

Comment: You can perhaps try Lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce

Comment: By the way you should use `setTimeout`.

Comment: Should I seperate the conditions throughout different functions then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.queue()` with `.delay()` to achieve requirement by passing the same `queueName` to both methods

```js
$({})
.delay(500, "delay")
.queue("delay", function() {
  console.log("do stuff")
}).dequeue("delay");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at this.

Use timeouts.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
if (r1x>=p1x && r1x<=p1y){
    planta1.style.width="50px";
    planta1.style.top="-90px"
    planta1.style.left="30px"
    planta1.src="imagens/jogo_1/planta1_2.png";

    setTimeout(function() {
        planta1.style.width="100px";
        planta1.style.top="-100px"
        planta1.style.left="10px"
        planta1.src="imagens/jogo_1/planta1_3.png";

        setTimeout(function() {
            planta1.style.width="100px";
            planta1.style.top="-110px"
            planta1.style.left="10px"
            planta1.src="imagens/jogo_1/planta1_4.png";

            setTimeout(function() {
                planta1.style.width="100px";
                planta1.style.top="-120px"
                planta1.style.left="10px"
                planta1.src="imagens/jogo_1/planta1_5.png";
                coracao1.style.visibility="visible";
                coracao1.style.top="500px";
                coracao1.style.left="95px";
                pontosjogo1facil++;
            }, 500); // end last test

        }, 500); //end second test

    }, 500); // end first test
}
```

But I agree with some of the comments, I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't explain myself well, what I'm doing is making a game where you can water plants, and when you collide with them (by CSS top property) they grow up. What I wanted to do is make them grow up incrementally and not go straight up to the end of the conditions.